# Trouble with creating database table using jQuery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I am absolutely new to jQuery and ajax. Currently I am trying to create a table on my local sql server from a javascript file from which I am posting the statement to .php file to execute the statement.

.js file:

```
function executeStatement(sqlStatement){
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: sqlStatement,
      cache: false,
      url: "api.php",
      dataType: "text",
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      },
      success: function ()
      {
        alert ("Success!!");
      }
    });
  }
```

.php file:

```
  require_once('PhpConsole.php');
  PhpConsole::start();
  debug('HERE!!!');

  $sqlStatement = $_POST['sqlStatement'];

  $host = "*****";
  $user = "*****";
  $pass = "*****";
  $databaseName = "db_user_data";

  // Create connection
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName);

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
    $con->query($sqlStatement);
    header('Location: success.php');  
  }
```

I use PHP Console to debug .php files but in this case even the first log 'HERE!!!' is not printed to the console so I am wondering whether it even reaches this .php file. Anyway the event `success` within executeStatement method is reached and 'Success' printed even though  there are no changes in the database.By the way the .php file is also executed on the local server. Does someone has any ideas where the problem can be??

Thanks in advance

Comment: why send the whole query from javascript. just send the data you need in `json` format. `{username: 'hello', password: 'world'}`, set the `dataType` option in the `ajax` function as `json`, then in `PHP`, decode the `json` and do your PHP query in the PHP file

Comment: actually the sqlStatement variable contains something like 'CREATE TABLE bla bla' and it varies depending on the user

Comment: Oh my! I really hope you know what you're doing here. Allowing just ANY SQL statement to be sent to your backend is very insecure. Anyone that is able to access that page is able to delete your database or export sensitive data.

Comment: I know what are you thinking about and dont worry about it :)

Comment: is crazy even putting any sort of server side query statement in javascript... only send applicable data and create statements server side using results of `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your PHP code at the "$pass" variable:

```
require_once('PhpConsole.php');
PhpConsole::start();
debug('HERE!!!');

$sqlStatement = $_POST['sqlStatement'];

$host = "*****";
$user = "*****";
**$pass = "*****";**
$databaseName = "db_user_data";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
  $con->query($sqlStatement);
  header('Location: success.php');  
}
```

EDIT: Here is my revised JS code - this works perfectly for me as I am able to pass the code from an AJAX call to the PHP code and back. Try this:

```
var sqlStatement = "sqlStatement=SQLSTATEMENTHERE";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: sqlStatement,
  cache: false,
  url: "api.php",
  success: function ()
  {
    alert ("Success!!");
  }
});
```

Place the variable outside of your function and the ajax call inside to replace the old one. As for the PHP, i'll check that out in a second.

Comment: thats not the problem, I just made it while I was replacing the real info with '*' but thanks for the warning!

Comment: oh right, my bad then! - Do you mind posting a typical example of the posted $sqlStatement variable here? That may be where the problem is.

Comment: Sure! For instance like this: 'CREATE TABLE test (TelNr1 INT(64), address CHAR(64));'. The error is not in the sqlStatement, I tried to execute it directly in phpAdmin and I worked well...

Comment: Right, that checks out, so the only other place the error could be is in the JS. What i'm thinking now is that the 'sqlstatement' variable is not getting passed to the php code for some reason. Give me a few minutes and i'll have a look for you.

Comment: OK, thanks!!! But as I already mentioned I really think that the php file is not reached at all because even the first log is not printed out...

Comment: OK there you go, try that code and replace 'SQLSTATEMENTHERE' with the SQL statement.

Comment: Wait, I am not quite sure if that is some kind of syntax but why it should be like 'sqlStatement=CREATE TABLE test (TelNr1 INT(64), address CHAR(64));'??

Comment: you know how normal links are structured like url.com/index.php?var=1? an ajax call is very similar. It takes the url value and places any value(s) in the data parameter at the end. So  without my change, you would be calling: api.php?CREATE TABLE... which dosen't work. With my change, you are now calling api.php?sqlStatement=CREATE TABLE..., which is picked up correctly by PHP.

Comment: I am really new in this kind of stuff but isnt this way used just in the case of 'GET'??

Comment: yes it is, however when it comes to ajax, you must always do it like this, regardless of whether its 'POST' or 'GET'.

Comment: right, there is one more thing i'm going to try and if that does not work, then I have no idea where the issue is :/.

Comment: Thats fine, my code all works fine with the example sql you gave earlier, the only thing I can think of left is that you either have the wrong login details or you have insufficient permissions. I have tested my code just now and the table creates perfectly, so there is nothing wrong with the code. Just make sure you have the right details and permissions.

Comment: Finally it is working!!! I just woke up and tried it again to see some logs and it worked. I guess that just WAMP services needed to be restarted...